# How to remove reminder from event in android?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, reminders

When I set a reminder for an event can not remove it!
I've already test this code:

```
Uri reminderUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminder.id);
context.getContentResolver().update(reminderUri, getEmptyReminderContentValues(reminder), null, null);
context.getContentResolver().delete(reminderUri, null, null);
```

I seen some calendars include google calendar do this but some of them do not.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: let me know if below answer was any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following method to delete the reminder set on event

```
public static void deleteReminderOnEvent(Long reminderId) {
    Uri reminderUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminderId);
    int rows = contentResolver.delete(reminderUri, null, null);
}
```

**You need to use following method before above method to get the reminderId for the event and then pass it to above method.**

```
private static Long checkIfReminderExist(ContentResolver contentResolver, long eventId) {
    Long reminderId = null;

    String[] projection = new String[]{
            CalendarContract.Reminders._ID,
            CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD,
            CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES
    };

    Cursor cursor = CalendarContract.Reminders.query(contentResolver, eventId, projection);

    while (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
        reminderId = cursor.getLong(0);
    }

    cursor.close();

    return reminderId;
}
```

Comment: are you using checkIfReminderExist to get the reminderId ?

Comment: as this same code works for me. have you tried setting null or 0 values in minute ?

Comment: @ Punit Sharma 1) This code works for deleting single reminderId, how to do if the event has multiple reminders and i want to remove all reminders for that event ?         
 2) What does delete function return in this line of code                                               
 "int rows = contentResolver.delete(reminderUri, null, null);"